# Parsing using SAX fails because of '&' character in HTML

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I tried to parse an XML document (HMTL actually, but that does not matter) in Java with org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.

The document contains a line with an URL:

```
< link rel ="something" href="http://...&pg=2..." />;
```

The problem is, it is expected to have a semicolon (;) after that, so `&pg` becomes some symbol, and SAXBuilder gives an error because of that (no semicolon after &pg found).

Is there any parsing option to make SAX not interpret the character `&` as a symbol, but like a normal string?

The difference is, I do not want to **parse special character**, I want to parse characters `&something` **as they are**, it must be so by default actually,
 and the **main** problem is an **exception** thrown by Java class

```
org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder
```

Answer (score 2):

**&** is a special XML character. You would need to escape it to &amp; or wrap it around CDATA[] tag.

> I tried to parse an XML document (HMTL actually, but that does not
>   matter) in java

It does matter! If you use an XML editor to validate the **HTML source**. Does it complain of the same issue? Is it XML well-formed?

Keep in mind that many HTML sources are not XML well-formed. If you want to parse HTML then I would suggest use HTML parser. I used **JSoup** (open source) api to parse HTML in many of my projects.

Comment: yes, for example netbeans xml editor write the same about ;pg.
is this JSout parce to somthing jdom Element-like, so you could navigate to elements?

Comment: JSoup is Apache project, open-source. Its for parsing HTML and navigates the DOM-liked. You can select various nodes, attributes and extracts their data...